# Just wondering how can i convert this below query to a oracle query using merge statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

```
UPDATE WRK_VTNHMBENTEMP BEN
INNER JOIN wrk_vtnhmbenaccmap ACC ON BEN.WFID = ACC.WFID
LEFT OUTER JOIN vtsmbankbranch BNK ON BNK.BANKNAME = ACC.benbankname
BEN.CURRSTATUSDESC := NVL(BEN.CURRSTATUSDESC,'')||'|'||'Bank Name is not Valid: '||ACC.benbankname;Ben.CURRSTATUSCODE:='30'
where BEN.WFID=IN_WFID AND BNK.BANKBRANCHID IS NULL

;
```

Comment: This query only generates a syntax  error.  Please explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: im still new here. im just doing this on behalf of my brother. i just corrected a small mistake in that query. can you please check if you can help me convert it

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (That UPDATE will not run on both.)

Comment: Sorry my bad. He tried to convert the actual MySQL query to oracle using sqlines website. i will update the question with the actual query. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you posted so far, could be something like this (presuming that last line's `IN_WFID` represents some kind of a parameter):

```
MERGE INTO wrk_vtnhmbentemp ben
     USING (SELECT acc.wfid, acc.benbankname
              FROM wrk_vtnhmbenaccmap acc
                   LEFT JOIN vtsmbankbranch bnk
                      ON bnk.bankname = acc.benbankname
             WHERE bnk.bankbranchid IS NULL) x
        ON (ben.wfid = x.wfid)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET
      ben.currstatusdesc =
            NVL (ben.currstatusdesc, ' ')
         || '|'
         || 'Bank name is not valid: '
         || x.benbankname,
      ben.currstatuscode = '30'
           WHERE ben.wfid = in_wfid;
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. This is really helpful . Thanks a lot.